# Suspend the current function until the dialog is closed

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

The example has two windows, `Main` and `Foo`. `Main` is supposed to display the value input in `Foo` earlier after `Foo` is closed.

[image: Whole picture]

The code is as follows:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *

class Main(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Main, self).__init__()
        self.setupUI()

    def setupUI(self):
        self.label = QLabel('0')

        okBtn = QPushButton('Start Foo')
        okBtn.clicked.connect(self.startFoo)

        mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.label)
        mainLayout.addWidget(okBtn)
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)

        self.setWindowTitle('Main')
        self.show()

    def startFoo(self):
        foo = Foo()
        # I want the function to suspend until Foo() is destroyed, so I can set label's text as what I input earlier in `Foo`
        self.label.setText(str(foo.edit.text()))


class Foo(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Foo, self).__init__()
        self.setupUI()
        self.var = 0

    def setupUI(self):

        # QLineEdit
        self.edit = QLineEdit()

        # QPushButton
        okBtn = QPushButton('OK')
        okBtn.clicked.connect(self.setVar)

        # main layout
        mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.edit)
        mainLayout.addWidget(okBtn)
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)

        self.setWindowTitle('Foo')
        self.show()

    def setVar(self):
        self.var = self.edit.text()
        self.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Main()
    app.exec_()
```

Notice this part:

```
def startFoo(self):
    foo = Foo()
    # I want the function to suspend until Foo() is closed, so I can set label's text as what I input earlier in `Foo`
    self.label.setText(str(foo.edit.text()))
```

I want the function to suspend until Foo() is destroyed, so I can set label's text as what I input earlier in `Foo`. But the app just continued to run, which made `self.label`'s text a total blank(because `foo.edit.text()` was `None` when `Foo()` was started). I tried add a `QEventLoop` like this:

```
def startFoo(self):
    foo = Foo()

    loop = QEventLoop()
    foo.destroyed.connect(loop.quit)
    loop.exec_()

    self.label.setText(str(foo.edit.text()))
```

It doesn't work, either. So how to do the trick?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `exec_` instead of `show` to display the `Foo` dialog. The difference is that while `show` simply display the dialog window, `exec_` will execute it as modal, so you can interact only with that dialog while the UI thread is suspended until the dialog is closed.

```
import sys

from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *

class Main(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Main, self).__init__()
        self.setupUI()

    def setupUI(self):
        self.label = QLabel('0')

        okBtn = QPushButton('Start Foo')
        okBtn.clicked.connect(self.startFoo)

        mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.label)
        mainLayout.addWidget(okBtn)
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)

        self.setWindowTitle('Main')

    def startFoo(self):
        foo = Foo()
        foo.exec_()
        self.label.setText(str(foo.edit.text()))


class Foo(QDialog):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Foo, self).__init__()
        self.setupUI()
        self.var = 0

    def setupUI(self):

        # QLineEdit
        self.edit = QLineEdit()

        # QPushButton
        okBtn = QPushButton('OK')
        okBtn.clicked.connect(self.setVar)

        # main layout
        mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.edit)
        mainLayout.addWidget(okBtn)
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)

        self.setWindowTitle('Foo')

    def setVar(self):
        self.var = self.edit.text()
        self.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Main()
    ex.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Also, but this is mostly a personal advice and not a general rule, it's better to call `show` and `exec_` from outside the class implementing the widget. In this way you can differentiate the way a dialog window is shown (for example you can create a button to execute `show` and another one to display it modal by calling `exec_`.